# PHP Regex to extract phone numbers

Tags: php, regex

I would like to extract these phone number patterns using regex:

xxx.xxx.xxx, xxx-xxx-xxx, (xxx)xxx-xxxx, or (xxx) xxx-xxxx

I've done this:

```
preg_match_all('/\b[0-9]{3}\s*-\s*[0-9]{3}\s*-\s*[0-9]{4}\b/',$output,$matches);
```

But it only matches xxx-xxx-xxx your help would be appreciated. thanks!

Comment: i'm not good with regex but when i'm trying to do one i'm using this website : http://txt2re.com/index-php.php3 maybe it can help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(?:\(|\b)[0-9]{3}\s*\)?[.-]?\s*[0-9]{3}\s*[.-]\s*[0-9]{3,4}\b
```

This should do it for you.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/iJ7bT6/17