# regex: show all phone numbers

Tags: php, regex

i want to see all phone numbers in my string. right now it has only one number in the array 'match' how can i get all the numbers in my array?

```
$str = "djvdsfhis 0647382938 rdfrgfdg tel:0647382938 rfgdfgfd 06 47 38 29 
38 fdgdfrggfd tel:06-47382938 cxgvfdgsfdc";
$arr = '~\d{2}-\d{8}|\d{10}~';
$success = preg_match($arr, $str, $match);
if ($success) {
    echo "Match: ".$match[0]."<br />"; 
    print_r($match);
}
```

i get this as output:

```
djvdsfhis ffgfg 0647382938 rdfrgfdg tel:0647382938 rfgdfgfd 06 47 38 29 38 fdgdfrggfd tel:06-47382938 cxgvfdgsfdc

Match: 0647382938
Array ( [0] => 0647382938 )
```

but i want to have my array like this:

```
Array ( [0] => 0647382938 [1] => 0647382938 [2] => 06-47382938
```

Comment: So what is the difference between `0647382938` and say `20190128`. Both are numbers and in the string. What makes it a phone number?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Regex to extract phone numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34885393/php-regex-to-extract-phone-numbers)

Comment: @executable his problem isn't with the regex, it's with the array that is output that doesn't give him all of his results but the first. Thus it's not a duplicate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.preg-match-all.php). Which will output an array of all of the results of your regex, in this instance an array of the numbers.

```
$str = "djvdsfhis 0647382938 rdfrgfdg tel:0647382938 rfgdfgfd 06 47 38 29 
38 fdgdfrggfd tel:06-47382938 cxgvfdgsfdc";
$arr = '~\d{2}-\d{8}|\d{10}~';
$success = preg_match_all($arr, $str, $match);
if ($success) {
    print_r($match);
}
```

Test it here :

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/350d10b1be46ce3a5851d7671750bac28f9110f0

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [T-Regx tool](https://t-regx.com) which has automatic delimiters:

```
pattern('\d{2}-?\d{8}')->match($str)->all();
```